# name 'InMemoryUploadedFile' is not defined in django model?

Tags: django, django-models, python-imaging-library

So basically I have a django model which has a filefield. I'd like to resize images that get submitted and I have this code here to do that

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    img = Image.open(self.media)

    output = BytesIO()

    original_width, original_height = img.size
    aspect_ratio = round(original_width / original_height)
    desired_height = 100
    desired_width = desired_height * aspect_ratio

    img = img.resize((desired_width, desired_height))

    img.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=90)
    output.seek(0)

    self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField', "%s.jpg" % self.image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(output), None)

    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The error im getting is "name 'InMemoryUploadedFile' is not defined". How do I fix this? Also a side question. The model also takes in videos. How would I resize a video? This is just a side question the InMemoryUploaded is the main question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you import InMemoryUploadedFile?

please import it first

```py
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
```

Comment: I wasn't aware it was an import. I did some digging in the Django documentation and say it was a class so I though I'd need to make one but since I've never worked with this before I was lost

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `InMemoryUploadedFile` to save a file. Also you get the error because you never import it. To import it `from django.core.files import InMemoryUploadedFile`. Instead of it you should better use `ContentFile`:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

...
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    img = Image.open(self.media)

    output = BytesIO()

    original_width, original_height = img.size
    aspect_ratio = round(original_width / original_height)
    desired_height = 100
    desired_width = desired_height * aspect_ratio

    img = img.resize((desired_width, desired_height))

    img.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=90)
    output.seek(0)
    
    self.image.save("%s.jpg" % self.image.name.split('.')[0], ContentFile(output), save=False)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```